# Progress updates from a long-running, recursive Clojure function

Tags: clojure, callback, watch

I wrote this helper function:

```lisp
(defn iterate-converge
  "Returns the value from calling (f x) some number of times, until
  `x` changes by less than a tolerance, `tol`. Will not execute more
  than `b` (e.g. bailout) times."
  [f x0 tol b]
  (loop [f f x x0 tol tol b b i 0]
    (if (>= i b)
      (throw (ex-info "Failed to converge"
                      {:type ::failed-to-converge :tol tol :b b}))
      (let [x' (f x)]
        (if (< (abs (- x x')) tol)
          x'
          (recur f x' tol b (inc i)))))))
```

Depending upon the parameters, this can take a significant amount of time. I'd like the function report on its progress. I don't want it to be tied to console output (e.g. `println`).

My current ideas:

1. Add a callback function as a parameter. Call it for each pass through. This allows for push notification.
2. Add an atom as a parameter. Update it for each pass through. This would allow for polling *or* push notification by using [add-watch](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/add-watch).
3. Add a core.async channel as a parameter. Similar to (1) above but may give better multicore performance.

What would you do and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it return a lazy sequence of candidate answers. Then you can iterate through them at your leisure, stopping whenever the answer is acceptable, or when you decide it's taken too long and you want to give up.

Comment: I like the spirit of what you are saying -- because (a) it is good Clojure advice in general and (b) it is not what I was expecting. That said, I don't think it fits with the goals and responsibilities of the function above. For example, I use it to do Taylor expansions. The caller, by design, should not make a decision on whether to continue or not. That is the role of `iterate-converge`. What the caller does want is a 'status update' from time to time.

Comment: So it returns a lazy sequence of status updates, each of which contains some way to take meaningful action. There's no need for any "out of band" communication, which would be much harder to manage. A caller who doesn't care about the updates just calls `last` on the update-seq and gets the final answer; an interested caller steps through the updates one at a time and does whatever.

Comment: Or you could split your solution into two methods - a new one that produces the lazy-seq that @amalloy describes and then change this one  to perform your side-effect notifications and returns `last`. As a benefit, this wrapper function could have the responsibility of deciding when the result was "good enough", and make the inner function infinitely recur.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would rank these options in reverse order, #3 being most flexible because then you can handle the output in more interesting (and fun) ways.

If you are looking for more options, I can recommend the [Narrator library](https://github.com/ztellman/narrator) as a way to accurately produce periodic reports of long running processes.